# Get 2 Values From Big Json Object

Tags: android, jackson

I am working with the follow json object that I retrieve from the google places api

```
{

    "debug_info":[
    ],
    "html_attributions":[
    ],
    "result":{
        "address_components":[
            {
                "long_name":"109",
                "short_name":"109",
                "types":[
                    "street_number"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name":"Torstraße",
                "short_name":"Torstraße",
                "types":[
                    "route"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name":"Mitte",
                "short_name":"Mitte",
                "types":[
                    "sublocality",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name":"Mitte",
                "short_name":"Mitte",
                "types":[
                    "sublocality",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name":"Berlin",
                "short_name":"Berlin",
                "types":[
                    "locality",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name":"Berlin",
                "short_name":"Berlin",
                "types":[
                    "administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name":"Germany",
                "short_name":"DE",
                "types":[
                    "country",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name":"10119",
                "short_name":"10119",
                "types":[
                    "postal_code"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "adr_address":"\u003cspanclass=\"street-address\"\u003eTorstraße109\u003c/span\u003e,\u003cspanclass=\"postal-code\"\u003e10119\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspanclass=\"locality\"\u003eBerlin\u003c/span\u003e,\u003cspanclass=\"country-name\"\u003eGermany\u003c/span\u003e",
        "formatted_address":"Torstraße109,10119Berlin,Germany",
        "geometry":{
            "location":{
                "lat":52.5300431,
                "lng":13.40297
            }
        },
        "icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
        "id":"18c00ced59b4a7fb929dde10a01169517666eec5",
        "name":"Torstraße109",
        "reference":"CpQBiQAAAGrYOH9GhUIR5_9XJm8YPZYoudNVoYeIWwD1-zFzjdUp2eKujIt85bUM78FWiY9OgGm2pPoxnCjE5EMhXNz9hiPcLLybacpdSQ10x0mO8UQNs1Mj-EyjGMfBaowMSAxeye_2aDvCyJEk5JAkzTkqXenGi60Dx24o5zKTH1nt1yDBJ3BlKb7Uaas6dBTz2GoqKBIQNFg_NmrCnRGgLxw5VEvtghoU6fl4owiC-5mNZ5RCjS976-S1fyQ",
        "types":[
            "street_address"
        ],
        "url":"https://maps.google.com/maps/place?q=Torstra%C3%9Fe+109,+10119+Berlin,+Germany&ftid=0x47a851e486a78201:0xec18bf6093c5c499",
        "vicinity":"Mitte"
    },
    "status":"OK"

}
```

The only properties that I want to **pull from it are lat, lng and formated_address.**

**What is the most effiecent way to do this using jackson?**

I know I can write a custom deserializer but then I would have to call jsonParser.nextToken too many times.

What is a better way to go about this problem?

**EDIT**

The best I can come up with a the moment is this

```
public class LocationDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Location> {
    @Override
    public Location deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Location location = new Location();

        int len = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            String currentName = jsonParser.getCurrentName();
            if (currentName != null) {
                if (jsonParser.getCurrentName().equals("formatted_address")) {
                    location.setDescription(jsonParser.getText());
                } else if (jsonParser.getCurrentName().equals("lat")) {
                    location.setLatitude(jsonParser.getDoubleValue());
                } else if (jsonParser.getCurrentName().equals("lng")) {
                    location.setLongitude(jsonParser.getDoubleValue());
                    break;
                }
            }
            jsonParser.nextValue();
        }
        return location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you not picking up the keys by it's values ?

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
```

Where response is the response you received from Google.

Then to get your values:

```
JSONObject address = json.getJSONObject("result");
String formattedAddress = address.getString("formatted_address");


JSONObject locationData = address.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
Location location = new Location();
location.setLatitude(locationData.getDouble("lat"));
location.setLongitude(locationData.getDouble("lng"));
```

You need to import

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Comment: Well I am using the jackson library for other deserialization/serialization and it is working well. I thought it would be good to be consistent. Also I can cut down on alot of boiler plate code with the following line 

Location location = objectMapper.readValue(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(), Location.class);

Doesn't the JSONObject have to iterate through the object anyway?

Comment: Obviously you can adjust what I have provided above to the Jackson Library you are using. I'm not familiar with it so I can't tell you how, but the idea is the same, to get a hold of the particular json nodes to access the values, and not iterate through the whole json response

Comment: How do you know if it is obvious if you don't know the library?

Comment: Because it's a Json parsing library and this is a key option of JSON.

Comment: sorry, i don't buy it